# Jquery data-role collapsible events aren't being captured in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

Could anybody please let me know why the following code isn't working when i am using with Jquery mobile JS

http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/7/
This is my code

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content" id="dd">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap" id="result"></div>
</div>



var response = {
  "Restaurants": [{
    "RestrntArea": "Haii",
    "cust_loc_id": "374"
  }, {
    "RestrntArea": "rerrrwe",
    "cust_loc_id": "373"
  }]
}
showLabels();

function showLabels() {
  //$("#result").html("");
  var favoriteresultag = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < response.Restaurants.length; i++) {
    var name = response.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
    if (name) {
      favoriteresultag +=
        '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible"><h3>' +
        name +
        ' <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon "></a></h3></div>';
    }
  }
  $("#result").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
    alert('Expanded');
  });
  $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function() {
    alert('Collapsed');
  });
});
```

Why the collapse and expand even'ts are  being captured ??

Instead of document ready i tried with al the page events of mobile . But no luck .

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle I can't tell which version of jQM you are using. You have checked version 1.3 but then added the 1.4 css. Assumin version 1.4, I have updated your fiddle:

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/znz17ctm/11/)

Basically, you need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach the events because the collapsibles do not exist at the time of the bind. Also the event names are actually **[collapsibleexpand](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand)** and **[collapsiblecollapse](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-collapse)**.

So use on() instead of bind() by handling the event on the parent div and delegating it to all items with class my-collapsible that exist now or added dynamically:

```
$("#result").on('collapsibleexpand', '.my-collaspible', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
});

$("#result").on('collapsiblecollapse', '.my-collaspible', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});
```

Comment: I solved it this way $("#result").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create").trigger('pagecreate'); and then afterwards 
  $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {

 
 $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
});

$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});

Comment: @PreethiJain, in 1.4 you can use enhanceWithin() instead of trigger("create"), and my solution might have better performance as it does not require the whole page to be recreated each time you add items...